# How to implement recursion using SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID, date, amount, amount2
```

Column `amount2` has values only in the first row.
I need to recursively calculate each row of column `amount2` using values from previous row of this column and also column `amount`

- second row for `amount2` should be: first row value of `amount2` - second row value of `amount`
- third row for `amount2` should be: second row value of `amount2` - third row value of `amount`
  ...

I tried to use following code, but it does not work:

```
SELECT   
    first_column,  
    CASE   
        WHEN second_column IS NULL THEN LAG(first_column, 1, first_column) OVER (ORDER BY row_id) - LAG(first_column, 1, first_column) OVER (ORDER BY row_id DESC)  
        ELSE second_column  
    END AS calculated_second_column
from table;
```

Reproducible example:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (  
    id INT,  
    date DATE,  
    amount DECIMAL(10,2),  
    amount1 DECIMAL(10,2)  
); 




INSERT INTO your_table_name (id, date, amount, amount1)  
VALUES  
    (234, '2020-01-01', 4, 10),  
    (234, '2020-01-02', 7, NULL),  
    (234, '2020-01-03', 10, NULL),  
    (234, '2020-01-04', 15, NULL),  
    (234, '2020-01-05', 6, NULL);
```

I expect to have in column amount1; 10, 10-7=3, 3-10=-7, -7-15=-22, -22-6=-28

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and the expected output for your sample data; and, if it is not immediately obvious, an English (not code) explanation of why the sample input data is transformed to give that output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find first row using the `FIRST_VALUE` analytic function and then use the `SUM` analytic function to find a cumulative total and subtract:

```sql
SELECT  id,
        dt,
        amount,
        -- Find the first amount + amount1 value
        FIRST_VALUE(amount + amount1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt)
        -- Subtract the cumulative sum of the amount values
        - SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt)
        AS amount1
FROM    your_table_name;
```

Or, using `COALESCE` in the cumulative `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT  id,
        dt,
        amount,
        SUM(COALESCE(amount1, -amount)) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt)
          AS amount1
FROM    your_table_name;
```

Or, using a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT id, dt, amount, amount1
FROM (
  SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AS rn
  FROM   your_table_name t
)
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (id)
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES (dt, amount, amount1)
  RULES (
    amount1[rn>1] = amount1[cv(rn)-1] - amount[cv(rn)]
  );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
  id      INT,
  dt      DATE,
  amount  DECIMAL(10,2),
  amount1 DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO your_table_name (id, dt, amount, amount1)
VALUES
(234, DATE '2020-01-01',  4,   10),
(234, DATE '2020-01-02',  7, NULL),
(234, DATE '2020-01-03', 10, NULL),
(234, DATE '2020-01-04', 15, NULL),
(234, DATE '2020-01-05',  6, NULL);
```

All output:

| ID | DT | AMOUNT | AMOUNT1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 4 | 10 |
| 234 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | 7 | 3 |
| 234 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 10 | -7 |
| 234 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | 15 | -22 |
| 234 | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | 6 | -28 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z2xyvq80)

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to change the code, because I have also another problem, where:
second row for amount2 should be: second row value of amount+first row value of amount2-first row value of amount and so on, do you have any idea how to to this? Thanks

Comment: @Hena The `MODEL` clause is easy to change to that logic. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Je0OHlyj) - which also contains other options.